# Assigning an NSView to a window's contentView in the NIB

Tags: xcode4, nib

I am doing an exercise that assigns a view programmatically, but in which the author says, "We could do this in IB, but let's do it in code".

Here is the setUp.

1) 2 nib files, one "MainMenu" , the other an "ActivityView" nib.  In this case, the "MainMenu" nib contains the Window and the contentView. The "ActivityView" contains a view, whose file's Owner is a subclassed NSViewController, which is instantiated in the "MainMenu" nib.
The other thing is that the AppDelegate contains an IBOutlet to the "ActivityView" object in the MainMenu nib file.
So, programmatically, in the "applicationDidFinishLaunching" (of the AppDelegate), the code that is used, and works is:

```
    self.window.contentView=ac.view // where ac is an NSViewController Subclass
```

I would like to understand how to do this in the IB, but have been unable to do so. The closest was a suggestion to copy and paste the view from the 2nd nib, ( which works) but does not seem elegant, or perhaps this is the way it is done. Connecting the view outlet of the ActivityController ( i.e. the owner of the ActivityView's nib) in the MainMenu nib to the view of the window, does not work.  There is a good chance I am not asking the correct question, so would appreciate some insights into what the issue is that I am missing.